# why my program has out of bounds exception?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mid {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int student;
    int arr [][]=new int[student][5];
    String str[]= {"science","math","english"};
    
    public void score() {
        System.out.println("how many student?");
        student=scan.nextInt();
        
        for(int i=0;i<student; i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
                System.out.println("input"+(i+1)+"student "+str[j]+"score");
                arr[i][j]=scan.nextInt();
                }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to input the number of students and then the grades of the students.
It keeps happening out of bounds exception... How can I solve it?

Comment: You allocate an array and *then* ask the user how big the array needs to be. That needs to happen in the opposite order

Comment: Think about what happens if `studunt` is null then you try to use `int arr [][]=new int[student][5];`. Yes, it will be an array of 0 length. Define `student` first, or move `int arr[][]` to be after you set the value of student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are not assigning any value to `student` before using it in the `arr` so the value of `student` by default by java will be assigned to 0.

To solve the issue you can simple take the input of "how many students?" before initializing the `arr`, like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mid {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int student;
    System.out.println("how many student?");
    student=scan.nextInt();
    int arr [][]=new int[student][5];
    String str[]= {"science","math","english"};

public void score() {
    
    for(int i=0;i<student; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
            System.out.println("input"+(i+1)+"student "+str[j]+"score");
            arr[i][j]=scan.nextInt();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int student=scan.nextInt();` would be nicer